# Elastic search, unique query result

Tags: elasticsearch

Imagine the following data :

```
data: [
  {  A: 1
     B: 1
     C: 1
  }
  {  A: 1
     B: 1
     C: 2
  }
  {  A: 3
     B: 1
     C: 23
  }
  ... 
]
```

When I query, I would like to receive every data that has its value B as 1, but I don't want them to share the same A value. In other words I would like my query result to contain unique A values. So in this example I would have either C = 2, 23 or C = 1, 23. Is this achievable in elastic search ?

Comment: Is my question wrong or should I assume that there is no way ?

Comment: I can't see a way to achieve that. I think you should consider to ask to elasticsearch mailing list, as most gurus are there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research, I have learned that, there is no way to achieve this as of now. Elastic search does not support such an operation.